# How can I access my Windows file system from Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I found your thread on accessing windows files/hard drive using Ubuntu.
I followed the directions of using `sudo fdisk` to reveal the partitions, but when I do it, I get a response telling me to enter the (`sudo`) password?

I enter the one I created when I installed Ubuntu yesterday. It tells me that is incorrect and it wont let me type.

My Windows is suddenly logging me in as a *guest user*. It wont give me access to any of my files, etc.

I really need to get to my files and offload them onto my external hard drive before this thing dies on me.

Answer (score 0):

The root password (`sudo`) is the password you set when you installed Ubuntu or whatever else if you changed it. Open a terminal in Ubuntu and type `su`. That will ask you for a password which you can keep typing and trying possibilities of what you might have originally set it to (if you've forgotten).

Other than that, a fdisk isn't really needed. You should be able to go into a partition manager (probably in the system menu, haven't used Ubuntu in a while) and see a partition formatted in NTFS (probably). You should be able to mount it from there and then simply browse through the files like normal.

Comment: `sudo` is not a root password. It's a program for gaining elevated privileges.

Comment: It's in brackets so that she knows that I'm talking about when I say the root password. I'm aware sudo is an application, however I'm trying to keep the jargon easy seeing as she isn't a 'savvy girl'